# Printf w/ Eclipse CDT Issue

Tags: c, printf, eclipse-cdt

Long story short I'm running Eclipse CDT.  Below is my code, a simple input character function.  However when I run it (without errors*) it requres me to input a character for the variable 'c' before displaying the printf statement.  I have tried using a puts statement as well as making two printf lines to no avail.  Can someone please direct me to the best solution, or tell me if this is more likely a eclipse cdt issue.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char c;
    printf("Please input a character: %c\n", c = getchar());
    if ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z'))
        printf("%c is a lower-case letter.", c);
    else if ((c >= 'A') && c<= 'Z')
        printf("%c is a capital letter.", c);
    else if ((c >= '0') && c <= '9')
        printf("%c is a digit!", c);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: I think this may not be the same issue... Added a possible answer below.

Comment: @jwismar: Right I didn't catch that.

Comment: getchar() returns an int, not a char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines:

```
char c;
printf("Please input a character: %c\n", c = getchar());
```

are not correct and are the reason you have to input a char before the print occurs.

The following will work correctly:

```
int c;
printf("Please input a character: ");
fflush( stdout );
c = getchar();
```

You might also want to look at:

```
isupper()
islower()
isdigit()
```

which are (normally) found in `<ctypes.h>`

Comment: Could you explain what this line specifically does: fflush( stdout)

Comment: Per "The C Programming Language":
fflush() causes any buffered but unwritten data to be written; on an input stream, the effect is undefined.  It returns EOF for a write error, and zero otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have `c = getchar()`as a parameter to `printf`. This parameter has to be evaluated before `printf` can be called.

You might have better luck using:

```
printf("Please input a character\n");
c = getchar();
```

Although, as I read the comments added above, it sounds like there may be a buffering problem as well that will prevent the output from being written. But try this first.